# runtime error 462 with internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to access a webpage from excel using VBA.  I can get internet explorer to launch, and I see the webpage come up, but I get a runtime error 462 when I hit the  Do Until internet.ReadyState >= 4 line of code.  any ideas?  ultimately I want to be able to parse a site and get a list of the links on that site and pick one, and then "click" on that link.  suggestions and help would be great.  here is the function (that I found on the web) that I am using:

```
Public Sub clicklick()

Dim internet As Object
Dim internetdata As Object
Dim div_result As Object
Dim header_links As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim URL As String

Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
internet.Visible = True

URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+program+in+vba"
internet.Navigate URL


Do Until internet.ReadyState >= 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

Set internetdata = internet.Document
Set div_result = internetdata.getelementbyid("res")


Set header_links = div_result.getelementsbytagname("h3")

For Each h In header_links
    Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)
    Cells(Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1, 1) = link.href
Next

MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

thank you,
alan

Comment: The codes seems okay and getting links. What error comes to your PC. Put error screenshot as well.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error with VBA and
using     `Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium` instead of `Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` did not solve the problem. I solved the issue by going to IE Settings -> Internet Options -> Security and unchecking the "Enable protected Mode" option [image: Settings]

Comment: in my case both using InternetExplorerMedium and unsetting "Enable Protected Mode" solve the issue, although I do not understand why adding e.g. localhost:8080 (that's the address I am trying to navigate to) to Trusted Sites and setting its Security Level to Low, while unsetting "Enable Protected Mode" would not work - it really doesn't. I am working with legacy software anyway, and accept that lots of solutions are of a "workaround" type, but I would appreciate if there was less magick out there :(

Answer (score 1):

Try replcaing your lines :

```
Do Until internet.ReadyState >= 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
```

With:

```
While internet.busy
    DoEvents
Wend
```

**Full Code** (tested)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub clicklick()

Dim internet As Object
Dim internetdata As Object
Dim div_result As Object
Dim header_links As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim h As Object
Dim URL As String

Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
internet.Visible = True

URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+program+in+vba"
internet.Navigate URL

internet.Visible = True

While internet.busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Set internetdata = internet.Document
Set div_result = internetdata.getelementbyid("res")

Set header_links = div_result.getelementsbytagname("h3")

For Each h In header_links
    Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)
    Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = link.href
Next

MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai, thank you for the help.  this worked.  my issue now is that I want to really use this site (https://biz.yahoo.com/p/s_conameu.html), and I want to get the links for the various sectors listed on that site.  When I run the code, I get all theway to: Set div_result = internetdata.getelementbyid("res") and I get a runtime error '424' Object required message.  Is there an issue with trying the same thing with this type of website?