# The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable for specific website

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I tried to open website using below VBA code:

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim strURL As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE '
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://Google.com"

    Do Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

It's working for website like "google" etc.

But when I tried to open specific site like my company PLM " Agile (https://agileplm.XXXX.com/Agile/default/login-cms.jsp)" throwing error
"The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"

I could open the web page on explorer but throwing error while executing from below line

```
Do Until .readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Is this due to any protection over site or not?

Comment: I had the same error. I typically only use VBA + IE for very quick simple web scraping and/or if I need to share it quickly with a colleague etc. otherwise I use python + selenium. I wanted to quickly grab some info from our internal sharepoint / delve site and it failed with error 462 just like you said. I checked another website directly before and after and they both worked. I think the VPN / internal network is the core of the problem. I used python + selenium instead!

Answer (score 2):

I used early binding on this and created the object InternetExplorerMedium rather than InternetExplorer and it seemed to work.

Comment: another related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048013/runtime-error-462-with-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Internet Explorer disconnects from VBA (In my case some internal security settings). The solution is to reconnect Internet Explorer to VBA:

Include this code after the line IE is not responsive anymore and the existing Internet Explorer window will be assigned to = IEObject1

```
    Dim shellWins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim explorer As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    Set shellWins = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    
    For Each explorer In shellWins
        If explorer.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
            Set IEObject1 = explorer
            Debug.Print explorer.LocationURL
            Debug.Print explorer.LocationName
        End If
    Next
    
    Set shellWins = Nothing
    Set explorer = Nothing
```

If you have several IE windows open then this code picks the last one. You can choose between the windows by using the URL or LocationName if you need several open windows.

Comment: With some brief explanation your code would be great resource

Comment: @xlmaster The code looks through all open windows and if the name of the window matches "Internet Explorer" then the IEObject1 is set to it. Since it loops through all open windows and reuses the variable name (IEObject1) the value is overwritten. You could insert an if statement that checks if the URL matches the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with example code below may help you to solve your issue.

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True

    'Define URL
    URL = "https://agileplm.xxxx.com/Agile/default/login-cms.jsp"

    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL

    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

    'Webpage Loaded
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

    'Unload IE
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Reference:

[Automate Internet Explorer (IE) Using VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/)

If your issue persist than try to provide a detailed information, Whether you are having issue with opening the page or you got an error while checking the ready state of IE. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, still i am facing the same error, Run time error 462.

Comment: If possible for you than can you please try to post that URL? We can try to make a test with it to check for the issue. Other than that you can try to refer link below to get more information on that error. https://helpdesk.rs2tech.com/kb/article/6-error-462-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is-unavailable/

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim strURL As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://Google.com"
End With

For Each win In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    If win.Name Like "*Internet Explorer" Then
         Set IE = win: Exit For
    End If
Next

With IE
    Do Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, esp. as there are already three answers - furthermore please correct the code: `End With` is missing at the end.